# Get data from SQLite Database between two datepicker values

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a sqlite database and a winform. I want to get data from my database using this query.

```
String query = "select * from table where date >= '" + dateTimePicker1.Value + "' AND date <= '" + dateTimePicker2.Value + "' ";
```

When I run my program. I pick `3/8/2015` from the first datetimepicker and `3/10/2015` from the second. I was only able to display the values from `3/9/2015` and `3/10/2015` when I wanted to display values from `3/8/2015` as well. What could be the problem here? Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the type of `date` column?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about C# but in java,
when using Calendar objects, the int value of month starts from 0 (January = 0)
So u need to add +1 manually.

```
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
```

Hope this put you in correct track.